# Hide no shipping methods message in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide a specific Woocommerce shipping notice, that appears when no shipping methods are available in cart and checkout:

[image]

But I didn't find yet the way.

Any help will be appreciated.

I want to  remove this message from hook

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_no_shipping_available_html', '__return_false');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', '__return_false');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.